# Using Neo4j for multiple graphs

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working on an application that will store data(graphs) from multiple clients. Each client will have 4 graphs.
and will able to query each graph independly. each graph have one or two indecies, which will be used to start a cypher query.
Using neo4j how can i achieve this? is this possible using one Noe4j databse (server mode) any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If the client specific graphs are not connected (aka no relationships from nodes of client A to nodes of client B), use separate distinct indexes for each customer (or a label if going with 2.0.M02). E.g. use clientA_product and clientB_product as index names.

Any query will lookup the index and do a traversal. This guarantees not to switch accidentially into another client's graph. If you need a tighter separation you can do this by applying a [SecurityRule](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules) in your Neo4j server.

Comment: thanks very much. Yes each client graphs are isolated. But if there are lots  clients say 200 and more then its feasible to have four different indecies for each client graph ?

Comment: No worries with having hundreds of indexes.